# publish a message every 10 seconds mqtt

Tags: python, mqtt

I am new to mqtt and still discovering this interesting protocol.
I want to create a client in python that publishes every 10 seconds a message. Until now I succeed to publish only one message and keep the client connected to the broker.

How can I make the publishing part a loop ?

Below is my client:

```
import mosquitto
mqttc=mosquitto.Mosquitto("ioana")
mqttc.connect("127.0.0.1",1884,60,True)
mqttc.publish("test","Hello")
mqttc.subscribe("test/", 2)

while mqttc.loop() == 0:
pass
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sleep between calls:

```
import mosquitto
import time # import time module
mqttc=mosquitto.Mosquitto("ioana")
mqttc.connect("127.0.0.1",8000,60,True)
mqttc.subscribe("test/", 2)
while mqttc.loop() == 0:
    mqttc.publish("test","Hello")
    time.sleep(10)# sleep for 10 seconds before next call
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt # mosquitto.py is deprecated
import time

mqttc = mqtt.Client("ioana")
mqttc.connect("127.0.0.1", 1883, 60)
#mqttc.subscribe("test/", 2) # <- pointless unless you include a subscribe callback
mqttc.loop_start()
while True:
    mqttc.publish("test","Hello")
    time.sleep(10)# sleep for 10 seconds before next call
```

Comment: line 1 should read "import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt" (with client) then mqttc.connect line is missing a comma after the first argument, and True is an invalid bind address, this should be a string or omitted